# How to use columnDef.targets when wanting to pull specific columns from the database and putting into an array

Tags: javascript, mysql

[ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpvln.png)

e.g i need to pull the column from empid - mname

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#empList').DataTable({
    'fnCreatedRow': function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
      $(nRow).attr('empid', aData[0]);
    },
    'serverSide': 'true',
    'processing': 'true',
    'paging': 'true',
    'order': [],
    'ajax': {
      'url': 'fetch_emp.php',
      'type': 'post',
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSortable": false,
        "aTargets": [0,4]
      },

    ]
  });
});
```

I tried to change the target to "_all" string but still gets error